# Get a chef/knife/cloud/list_resource_command (LoadError) info when knife status

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I get some error when using the command "knife status"

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- chef/knife/cloud/list_resource_command (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/knife-openstack-1.3.2/lib/chef/knife/openstack_network_list.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `load'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `block in load_commands'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `each'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `load_commands'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:110:in `load_command'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:124:in `command_class_from'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:153:in `subcommand_class_from'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/knife.rb:214:in `run'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:148:in `run'
    from /home/bxu/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-12.8.1/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/knife:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/knife:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is my current environment

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

knife -v
Chef: 12.8.1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have incompatible versions of `knife-openstack` and `knife-cloud`. Check if there are compatible versions or possibly uninstall both if you don't need them.